# Can I divide mysql result by sum only in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data:

```
date        | clicks
2016-01-01  |  50
2016-01-02  |  150
2016-01-03  |  70
2016-01-04  |  24
2016-01-05  |  38
2016-01-06  |  30
2016-01-07  |  78
2016-01-08  |  40
```

I need to split up sum(clicks) by 100(or more) and return dates.

Output:

```
date_start |   date_finish | sum(clicks) <= 100
2016-01-08 |  2016-01-07  | 118 (40 + 78)
2016-01-06 |  2016-01-03  | 162 (30 + 38 + 24 + 70)
2016-01-02 | 2016-01-02  | 150
2016-01-01 | 2016-01-01 | 50
```

I can do this it use programming language. But can I do it use only sql query?

Thanks

Comment: the output doesn't make any sense, unless you support time traveling. how can `finish` be EARLIER than `start`? and what does `sum(clicks) by 100` mean? you want to count clicks in groups of 100?

Comment: @MarcB You dont need TimeTravel *(even I want my hover board)* just `date DESC`, Still the `sum(clicks)` doesnt make sense

Comment: This is an inherently iterative process. In some languages, you can use recursive CTEs.  In MySQL, you can use variables.  However, if you have a solution using a programming language, you might as well use that.